# Wix SubDirectories in ComponentGroups

Tags: wix

I want to predefine Subfolders for my ComponentGroups.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?include Constants.wxi?>
  <Fragment>

    <ComponentGroup Id="CG.MYLIBRARY" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="C.MYLIBRARY" Guid="*">
        <File Id="MYLIBRARY" Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
      </Component>


      <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG.DependencyLibrary" />

      <!-- Resources -->

      <Component Directory="Configuration">
        <File Id="MyFile" Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)\Configuration\MyFile" />
      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

So I want `MyLibrary.dll` at my TopDirectory - where ever is "INSTALLFOLDER",
but I want automaticly `MyFile.xml` in a Subdirectory named `Configuration`.

```
#InstallFolder
-> MyLibrary.dll
-> DependencyLibrary.dll
#InstallFolder\Configuration
--> MyFile.xml
```

But when I try it like that - i just get:

> The Component/@Directory attribute cannot be specified when the
>   Component element is nested underneath a Directory element. If this
>   Component is a member of a ComponentGroup where
>   ComponentGroup/@Directory is set, then the Component/@Directory
>   attribute should be removed.

Why do I have to remove the `Directory`-Element, when i just want subfolders under the given Directory in my ComponentGroup?

Comment: It's something that isn't yet supported: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use this construct (ComponentGroup), but this compiles:

```
<...>

<Fragment>
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject4">
      <Directory Id="Configuration" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
 </Directory>
</Fragment>

<...>

<Fragment>
 <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">      
    <Component Id="C.MYLIBRARY" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
       <File Source="1.txt" />
    </Component>
    <Component Directory="Configuration">
       <File Source="2.txt" />
    </Component>
 </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: this answers my question anyway